# Content script doesn't see changes in web page with popup

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I'm trying to create a chrome extension that automatically fills out Broadway lottery forms (e.g.https://lottery.broadwaydirect.com/show/six-ny/). The lottery appears as a popup, so when the content script is loaded the popup is not immediately part of the html. However, I added a check (shown below) that consistently checks if the popup form has loaded, but the script doesn't seem to register changes in the DOM even when the popup appears. Has anyone else experienced this / do I have to do something else for my content script to "fetch" the new webpage html?

```
  function waitForDiv() {
    if (checkForDiv()) {
      fillForm();
    } else {
      console.log("div not here");
      // If the div is not found yet, wait and check again after a short delay (e.g., 500 milliseconds).
      setTimeout(waitForDiv, 500);
    }
  }

  function checkForDiv() {
    const targetDiv = document.getElementById("dlslot_name_first"); 
    return targetDiv !== null;
  }
```

When I put the code for checking the Div in the Google Chrome console after the popup appears, it returns true but for some reason my code returns false always.

Comment: If you inspect the popup in devtools you will see it's inside an `iframe`, so you need to wait for `iframe` first (use MutationObserver), then wait for the actual element to appear in `iframeElem.contentDocument`.

Comment: that was my issue, tysm!